# how to use string left function in hql

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql, criteria-api

I have a sql query like this

```
select column from table where path = left('INPUTSTRING', length(path));
```

and trying to accomplish it in hql like this,

```
  return session.createQuery("from Table where Path = left(:input, length(Path))").
                            query.setParameter("input", inputPath).
                            .list();
```

and getting an error like this

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: left near line 1
```

how to get this done? What is the corresponding string function in hql? Is there a solution for this using criteria query apis?

Comment: I'm not sure if hbl support left function, try to use NamedNativeQueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `left()` is not supported by the `MySQLDialect`. See the list of HQL supported functions on [API docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

Now you have left with 2 options.

1. Use `session.createSQLQuery()` method.
2. Create Your own `Dialect` class by extending the `MySQLDialect` and register the function there. This is told at hibernate forum [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=946761) explained well in a blog post [here](http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate).

Comment: Thanks, I changed the left function to substring() and still managed with the hql. Thanks for the api docs reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if HQL does this for you , but you can use IQuery/session.CreateSQLQuery() to use a raw SQL query to populate a mapped entity. I've never used it for substrings, but have used it for aggregate functions. Check chapter 13 of the NHibernate docs and see if that does it for you. You can check the query substitution available in Nhibernate - [here](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-3-isessionfactory-configuration#3%282E%295%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Optional_configuration_properties)