# Convert SQL to HQL | Order By with LEFT(not join)

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-order-by

I am trying to order a result set based on partial order of a column using the following query:

> select ID,NAME from person order by LEFT(NAME,2) desc

How can I write an equivalent Hibernate Criteria/HQL?

I have looked up in the Hibernate Reference manual, I am not able to find anything that relates to the LEFT sql-function.
I am working on DB2, hibernate version is 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like following but Left(2,Name) is not sure its work fine or not..tri it if it wrong ignore it.i'm also looked for that but there is no query with order by left..any way you can use ascending or descending and by using string methods you can read only partial data.

```
   Query query=session.createQuery("select p.ID,p.NAME  from Person p ORDER BY    LEFT(2,"NAME") DESC");
```

Comment: The above option did not work, as Hibernate does not support the Like function as listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634338/how-to-use-string-left-function-in-hql. Can someone close this question and or mark as similar-duplicate of the added link?