# Hibernate createSQLQuery does not accept Left function

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve a distinct list of first characters of a specific field but hibernate returns following error.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected token: LEFT near line 1, column 17 [Select DISTINCT LEFT(name,1)
```

**Code**

```
Query query = sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery(
                        "Select DISTINCT LEFT(name,1) from Name 
                         WHERE age = :age");
query.setParameter("age", age);
return query.list();
```

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634338/how-to-use-string-left-function-in-hql) that did not help.

**Expected Output**

If I search for age 12, it should return first character of names whose age value is 12, for example: a,b,f,g,k,l,z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substring instead.

```
Select DISTINCT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) from Name WHERE age = :age
```